# Bidirectional-streaming in Android causing OOMs

Tags: android, grpc, grpc-java

I've set up a bidirectional stream construct in an Android app, where I am currently using the mechanism to send chunks of large files.  The problem I am having is that my app will receive a request message for a file, then I'll respond with potentially hundreds of MBs worth of response GRPC messages, frequently causing an OOM.  Pseudo code:

```
public class Myclass implements StreamObserver<CameraRequest>, Closeable {
  ...

  public void onNext(Request req) {
    for (Chunk chunk : getChunks(req))
      this.requestObserver.onNext(builder.setChunk(chunk).build());
  }

  ...
}
```

Is there some good way to rate limit the number of outstanding calls to onNext based on what has actually been put on the wire (and corresponding memory made freeable)?  IE only allowing 10 calls to onNext to be made, then subsequent ones block until the data for the preceding calls has successfully been sent by the underlying protocol stack?  I could implement a full e2e acknowledgement window in my wire protocol TCP style, but was hoping there was an easier/built in technique others were using.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Cast `requestObserver` to [`ClientCallStreamObserver`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/stub/ClientCallStreamObserver.html). You can then call `clientCallStreamObserver.isReady()` to check if you should stop sending.

You will then need notifications for when the RPC is ready for more messages, to resume sending. For that, implement [`ClientResponseObserver`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/stub/ClientResponseObserver.html) and call `clientCallStreamObserver.setOnReadyHandler(Runnable)` within `beforeStart()`.

Putting that all together, gets you something like:

```java
public class MyClass implements
    ClientResponseObserver<CameraRequest,CameraResponse> {
  private ClientCallStreamObserver<CameraRequest> requestObserver;
  private Iterable<Chunk> chunks;

  public void beforeStart(ClientCallStreamObserver<CameraRequest> requestObserver) {
    this.requestObserver = requestObserver;
    requestObserver.setOnReadyHandler(MyClass::drain);
  }

  public void onNext(CameraRequest req) {
    // I don't know if this assert valid for your protocol
    assert chunks == null || !chunks.hasNext();
    chunks = getChunks(req);
    drain();
  }

  public void drain() {
    while (requestObserver.isReady() && chunks.hasNext()) {
      Chunk chunk = chunks.next();
      requestObserver.onNext(builder.setChunk(chunk).build());
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the flow control example [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/f155d60e75ceeb4fff54c480deca3a92c016ccbd/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/manualflowcontrol).